# What will be my key in NSSortDescriptor

Tags: iphone, ios, nssortdescriptor

I want to sort my array in ascending and descending order. For that I have search on Google and thanks to StackOverflow I have got this answer,

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"inputtime" ascending:TRUE];
[myMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

But I dont understand what will be the KEY which is in code `inputtime`. As you see all the data is provided is in `NSMUtableArray` and `NSArray` form than what will be key? I have tried to read apple document but still does not understand what is the key. Plz help me on this. Do i have to create dictionary?

Comment: What kind of objects does your array contain? Can you post an example?

Comment: @Alladinian it contain string and number...

Comment: @Kane: The (now deleted) answer of Dharmbir Choudhary is correct. The exception is thrown because your `myMutableArray` is in fact an `NSArray` and not an `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to sort array.
It helped me, and for this code thanx to @Anoop Vaidya

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *descriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];
    NSArray *reverseOrder=[yourAry sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Answer (score 0):

Key is used when your array contain dictionary or Core data objects. 
But when your array doesnt have any objects like this and containing simple NSString objects,you just need to use 
"self" in place of key. It will surely work for you

Answer (score 0):

Kane I think it will work for you-

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"time" ascending:NO]];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Here time is the key on basis of which i am fetching data in descending order. You can define a key on the basis of which you have to fetch. If there is no key then put self in place of key.

> The Key will be on the basis of which you want to fetch data as in my example time is the key.

Hope this helps.